# .ovpn-configuration (sophos) file can not be imported

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have got a file `<myName>@nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn.ovpn`, which was created by a Sophos firewall especially for non-Windows systems.

When I try to create the VPN connection by "adding a stored vpn-configuration", the system tells me something like:

> vpn connection could not be imported .... no readable vpn informations.

Even the first line is not accepted:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote nnn.nnn.nnn. 443
```

Setting up the vpn-connection via a terminal window works fine:

`sudo openvpn --config <myName>@nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn.ovpn.ovpn`

The connection is established,

`ifconfig tun0` results in:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  Hardware Adresse 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet Adresse:10.nnn.2.3  P-z-P:10.nnn.2.3  Maske:255.255.255.0
          UP PUNKTZUPUNKT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:43 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:43 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:100 
          RX-Bytes:4282 (4.2 KB)  TX-Bytes:3524 (3.5 KB)
```

This doesn't really help, because I don't know how to go on to use this connection.

But I think it confirms that the `.ovpn-config-file` is ok. This means, that the `ubuntu-network-manager` does not work.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [cannot import saved openVPN configuration file in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/q/760345/348964)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot import saved openVPN configuration file in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760345/cannot-import-saved-openvpn-configuration-file-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's related to know [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/606365/comments/68)?

[cannot import saved openVPN configuration file in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760345/cannot-import-saved-openvpn-configuration-file-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts?newreg=843f1c15f5764c7986ad8a547bd344d8)

Try commenting out the following line, I was able to successfully import the VPN config:

```
route remote_host 255.255.255.255 net_gateway default
```

Comment: As stated in a answer in the question mentioned above, use `sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file FILE_NAME` to show what is the configuration error. `rror: failed to import 'FILE_NAME.ovpn': configuration error: unsupported 1th argument remote_host to “route” (line 7)`

Answer (score 0):

[Santiago's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013116/1121962) works. You have to separate the `.ovpn` file into both certificate and key files and put the files in `~/.cert` in Fedora 34.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, after commenting the line `route ... default`, while importing the `.ovpn` file, the network manager creates the certificates in the folder `~/.cert/nm-openvpn` automatically. `name-ca.pem`, `name-cert.pem`, `name-key.pem`.